# Why does a Thévenin equivalent exist but not a Norton Equivalent, and vice versa?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton

In the following diagram, the Thévenin equivalent of the circuit on the left is shown on the right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFM3Mb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, it appears that there is no Norton equivalent for this circuit.

Similarly, the following diagram shows a circuit whose Norton equivalent exists, but there appears to be no Thévenin equivalent for it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWT4ac.png)</sup>

Comment: The first Norton equivalent is an infinte current source driving a zero parallel resistor. That is indeterminate: it matches all possible Thevenin circuits without meaning anything.  The second Thevenin equivilant is an infinite voltage source driving an infinite series resistor. Again, that Thevenin circuit is indeterminate: it matches all and any Norton circuits and simultanously does not match any of them: it has no meaning.

Answer (score 7):

A Thevenin or Norton equivalent is a circuit that has the same I-V curve as some more complex linear network, but itself contains only two elements: a source and a resistor or conductor.

In your first circuit, resistor R1 is irrelevant to finding the Thevening equivalent. Since R1 is in parallel with a voltage source, the overall I-V curve is just a vertical line through 1 V, as if you had only a voltage source. Which is exactly what your Thevenin equivalent circuit shows.

The reason you can't find a Norton equivalent circuit is because a Norton circuit can't produce a vertical line I-V curve with finite element values. You could create (or at least think about) a Norton equivalent circuit in limit as \$I\to\infty\$, if you maintain \$G=\frac{I}{1\mathrm{V}}\$ as you increase I.

The second circuit is just the dual. It has a horizontal I-V curve, and a Thevenin circuit can't have a horizontal curve with finite values.